# Connecting 2 ethereum swarm nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, swarm

I have two geth nodes and I want to run 1 swarm node on each node.

I made a boot node for the two swarm nodes to communicate with each other.

I run the first swarm node with the following command and it runs fine

> ~/go/bin/swarm --bzzaccount $BZZKEY --datadir node1/ --ens-api '' --bootnodes 'enode://67bea43dc6a907956ef4b766e5f80bd8647f6136575bb393ab1ab569eb6396c1773e8d4d30b0642b02eeba2783b5e75bbe53861ef076793149fd31563eb07cb5@127.0.0.1:30910'

Then I run the second swarm node with the following command and it give the following error.

> ~/go/bin/swarm --bzzaccount $BZZKEY2 --datadir node2/ --ens-api '' --bzzport 7012 --bootnodes 'enode://67bea43dc6a907956ef4b766e5f80bd8647f6136575bb393ab1ab569eb6396c1773e8d4d30b0642b02eeba2783b5e75bbe53861ef076793149fd31563eb07cb5@127.0.0.1:30910'

Error

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30399: bind: address already in use

What do I need to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an alternate port for the devp2p (UDP) protocol aswell, with the flag `--port`. The default port is `30399`